# Strange behaviour of the Ctrl keys under X on Ubuntu 18.04 Dell XPS 15 9560

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xorg

After trying to fix the trackpad sensitivity under Wayland, and not being able to make use of the nvidia card under Wayland I decided to switch to X, but I have a strange issue with the control keys under X that I do not under Wayland.
Pressing the only the control key (left or right) seems to work but unfocuses the current selection, specifically making editing CSS in the Browser's Developer Console very hard because I can't simply press ctrl+C/V to copy/paste css styles. The Dell XPS 15 9560 has a Fn key that combined with the right control key activates the contextual menu without problems, but the single control key keeps doing this strange thing.
In settings > Region & Language > keyboard layout I can see it registers every key (even Fn+rControl as "Menu") but not any of the control keys.

I hope you an help me with this issue.

**Edit:** Here are an image of the keyboard mapping layout when pushing Fn+rightControl for the context menu action. When pushing only left or right control keys there is no response from the keyboard mapping layout.
[image: fn+right Control Keys]

Also, there's a small video from the FFDev developer console showing that everytime I push any control key (to copy/paste) the cursor becomes unfocused from the field.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpvyri5iuujx0bb/control-pressing.ogv?dl=0

Thanks!

**Edit 02**: Checking with evtest I see the message:

```
Event: time 1536961386.805167, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1d
Event: time 1536961386.805167, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1536961386.805167, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1536961386.901359, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1d
Event: time 1536961386.901359, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1536961386.901359, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1536961217.724127, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9d
Event: time 1536961217.724127, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1536961217.724127, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1536961217.820477, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9d
Event: time 1536961217.820477, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 0
```

If I keep pressing any of the control keys the value changes from 1 to 2, repeating until I stop pressing it.

**EDIT 03**: Stranger still, I have tried remapping the keys to make Super_L work as Control_L and viceversa. What happens is that the Control key keeps on "unfocusing" as before, even the function is that of Super_L. I also tried unmapping all functions from Control_L and it keeps on doing the "unfocusing" thing, even it has no other function right now.

I have run:

```
xmodmap -pm
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)

xmodmap -e "remove control = Super_L"
xmodmap -e "add mod 4 = Control_L"
```

For testing, I also ran:

```
xmodmap -e "remove control = Control_R"
```

Comment: Does this also happen with the left control key?

Comment: Yes, both left and right control keys have the same issue.

Comment: I have updated the question, to add an image of the keyboard mapping layout and a small video from my main issue, happens the same with the location bar in web browsers.

Comment: I have updated the question, since remapping the keys didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the issue ended up residing in the `~/.config/dconf` folder, I discovered it after creating a new user for testing and checking that the keyboard worked flawlessly.
I installed `dconf-editor` with `apt` so I could edit the configuration but after a long while I decided to just rename de dconf and setting up again to my liking the "settings" app and the "gnome-tweak" app.

EDIT: Finally found the real issue. It was in the gnome-tweaks settings, on Wayland works properly but on X the **Pointer Location** under *Keyboard & Mouse* was the culprit, after turning it off the Ctrl keys work flawlessly again.